# What are the benefits of using "apply" over "normal" module function invocation?

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir and I wonder what are the benefits of using `apply` to invoke a function of a module:

```
apply(Enum, :reverse, [[1, 2, 3]])
```

instead of using the normal invocation:

```
Enum.reverse([1, 2, 3])
```

When is the first one better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the name of the module, the function, and the number of arguments you wish to pass to it are known at compile time, there's no need to call `apply/3`. If any of those are chosen at runtime, `apply/3` is the only way to make the appropriate call. In a way it's like a very restricted subset of an "eval" function: it lets you store the name of the module and function and the arguments to pass to it in variables and it makes the appropriate call.

So, in short, you only need to use `apply/3` when it's impossible to do the task without it.